# How to get started on doing a research internship or a project in Mathematics?

Tags: undergraduate, international-students, internship, projects, india

I am an undergraduate student pursuing a Bachelor's degree in Mathematics at an Indian University. I want to get involved in a research internship,  or a project in Mathematics.

I don't know where to start.

I haven't got an impressive or a remarkable CV/Résume.

My professors have no idea of what a research internship or  a project is! Actually, we don't have the "culture" of doing a research internships, or projects at our university. No one does it. Again, when someone asks them about it, they just say, that we should focus on only mainstream academics like the course.

So, things are getting difficult for me. So, I am kinda feeling helpless. I am an inexperienced lad. I need some help.

I know nothing about research. I have seen some of my peers do some research and getting their papers published. I don't know, what they do? Do they select a research topic, read about it, build a problem for themselves that no one ever solved and then they try to solve it, they solve it and publish it. But these steps looks intimidating although they are very simple to write. I really need some guidance.

I have a life long dream of getting an admission on master's degree course on Pure Mathematics at some US university with a good amount of scholarship. I have heard that the scholarship process is really competitive and hard to get and doing research internships or projects puts you ahead in the competition. So, it seems to me kind of a necessity to engage myself in projects or internships.

Comment: What do you mean "My professors have no idea of what a research internship or a project is"?

Comment: @BryanKrause Well actually, we don't have the "culture" of doing a research internships, or projects at our university. No one does it. Again, when someone asks them about it, they just say, focus on only mainstream academics. So, things are getting difficult for me.

Comment: My understanding is that actual undergraduate research in mathematics is quite rare; unlike an empirical science, it takes longer in mainstream studies to get to the "edge" of knowledge in mathematics (the "edge" may be closer in some applied areas, where math and empirical research come together). So, it's not clear to me whether you're running into that aspect of mathematics or whether it's really a cultural thing. But, it seems vanishingly unlikely to me that you'd be successful just taking off on your own; research is hard and requires mentorship.

Comment: With your background you are nowhere close to being able to do math research.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What to do? Advice me so that I can fulfill my dream of havin' an edge to get admissions in a masters program in US for mathematics

Comment: Forget the research, focus on strong foundations, like real and complex analysis, general topology, abstract algebra.

Comment: @ThomasFinley I would expect for a masters program in the US in mathematics you need good undergraduate grades and to be able to afford to pay tuition. You should not expect any funding or scholarship for a masters program in the US.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, without guidance, this is very hard. What you need is an unsolved problem and those are both hard to find and difficult to solve. That is why advisors with more experience are helpful/essential to the process.

However, there is one thing that you might think about, and it might lead to a reasonable project.

Take something that you know well and think about what variations there might be in that. What change in a definition or a formula might lead to something "interesting" that you could follow up on. At the undergraduate level it doesn't need to be a major thing, just something different enough to be new.

Note that fields built upon axioms (analysis, algebra, topology...) all have definitions of things that provide the "interesting" parts to study. For example, the Peano Axioms don't talk about a "less than" relationship between integers, but giving a definition of that provides something interesting to study. Ultimately, it gets you to Calculus and beyond. But there is no reason that variations on definitions might not also be "interesting" and worth exploring.

Still hard, but at least it is the way lots of mathematicians think about things. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I have edited my question a bit. Mind taking a look at it, please?